# How does the position of an electron donating group affect acidity in benzoic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I  know that the closer the electron withdrawing group to the $\ce{-COOH}$, the stronger is the acid. I am interested as to how this relationship works out in the case of an electron donating group.

Comment: This is the exact goal of Hammett plots and analysis of linear free energy relationships (LFERs).

Comment: @Zhe, judging  by the question I guess your attempt here is to further confuse the person asking the question.. :P

Comment: @AlphaRomeo Yeah, that wasn't super helpful... Let's actually read the question and not just the title and try again: Electron donation groups increase the negative charge density on the conjugate base, which destabilizes the conjugate base. The less stable the conjugate base, the less acidic the corresponding acid. The effect is exactly opposite with electron withdrawing groups. The closer the substituent is on the ring, the stronger the inductive effects. Just be careful if you're working with substituents that can participate heavily via resonance.

Comment: Keep in mind, resonance effects do not matter much, since the $\ce{-COOH}$ isn't in conjugation with the ring.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12309/inductive-effect

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7683/ortho-effect-in-substituted-aromatic-acids-and-bases

Answer (score 1):

The strength of the acid is determined by strength of the positive charge that is on the carbonyl carbon so in case of the presence of an electron donating group you have also to check what is its inductive effect whether it has an electronegative part which would attract electrons towards it or not ....the best way is to draw the resonating structure for every case and you will reach how is the activity affected by the EDG in different positions..one last factor you have to bear in mind is that the presence of an OH group in ortho position to the COOH will form a hydrogen bond which makes it even more stable than other positions ..if we take salicylic acid as an example then the strength is ortho>meta>para